# bibliography conflict vs hyperref

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

I get this error "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`\begin{thebibliography}`" during building. When I delete the `hyperref` package, this error disappears.
My packages are as follows:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eqnarray,breqn}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{float}
```

What to do to have boath `hyperref` and references?

Comment: The `hyperref` package normally has to be loaded last: does moving the position help?

Comment: ...and don't load [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) twice...

Comment: I get no error when adding the minimum to make it a complete document. If the error remains after loading the `hyperref` package last, please provide the code of a *complete* document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that illustrates the error. Btw, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I move the hyperef package to the last but error has remained

Comment: My code is here:`\documentclass{elsart5p}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eqnarray,breqn}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Hi, \cite{aa}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}`

Comment: The error is "file document.bbl Line 1 line 1: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{thebibliography}"